# Serving jetty webapp from two directories simultaneously

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, vfs

In development I use jetty as the servlet container. I have the following development configuration:

- master project which has wabapp directory
- derived project which overrides some of the files in webapp directory

The master project webapp can be started in development mode thanks to providing appropriate `WebAppContext` to jetty.

Now I want to start derived project analogously, assuming that when request is made, there is an attempt to:

- get resource from webapp directory of derived project
- if it does not exists, get it from webapp directory of master project

I know that it is possible to override `WebAppContext#getResource()` method, however some libraries we use in the project seem to perform IO operations on wabapp directory on their own. For example by calling `ServletContext#getRealPath("/")`, and then reading files without use of `ServletContext#getResource()` method. The problem could be solved on lower level by some virtual file system on top of `File`, however it does not seem to be supported in JDK 1.6, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using something like `ResourceCollection` is sufficient:

http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/resource/ResourceCollection.html

Unfortunately the GWT's DevMode which I use is based on jetty 6, where ResourceCollection is unavailable. I extended the `Resource` class myself, and together with own GWT `JettyLauncher`, and thanks to small trick with setting `resourceBase` on `DefaultServlet` via reflection, I was able to serve webapp from two directories simultaneously.

```
protected void doStart() throws Exception {
    setClassLoader(new LauncherWebAppClassLoader());
    super.doStart();
    ServletHolder holder = getServletHandler().getServlet("default");
    Servlet servlet = holder.getServlet();
    Field field = servlet.getClass().getDeclaredField("_resourceBase");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(servlet, combinedResourceBase);
}
```